# The clock of computer restarted and CentOs can't boot GUI

Tags: linux, user-interface, centos, boot

My computer's clock has been restarted, after this restarting I turn on my computer and waited for my CentOS to boot. but I face a black page which contains :

```
****An error ocurred during the file system check. 
**** Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot 
****when you leave the shell. 
****Warning -- SELinux is active 
****Disabling security enforment for system recovery. 
**** Run 'setenforce 1' to reenable. Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):
```

I typed my password and I face #root line in the very black page. 
I really need my CentOs work in GUI . Please help me.

Comment: @jww Sorry, I didn't know that. thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to a root shell, try this command: "fsck -a" It will try to automatically fix error on your filesystem.